# Integrating an ack-based Actor with akka-stream

Tags: akka, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I have an Actor which has been designed to work with akka-io acking,
such that it will wait for an Ack when sending messages upstream (to the
network). This actor is the interface to an async application in
the backend.

I'd like to have a wrapper layer which allows me to convert this
Actor into an akka-streams `Flow[Incoming, Outgoing, ???]` so that
it can be integrated with newer libraries that expect such a
signature.

(Incoming messages from upstream are rare, so we don't care too
much about backpressuring there but it wouldn't be a bad thing to
have it.)

```
sealed trait Incoming //... with implementations
sealed trait Outgoing //... with implementations
object Ack

// `upstream` is an akka-io connection actor that will send Ack
// when it writes an Outgoing message to the socket
class SimpleActor(upstream: Actor) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case in: Incoming if sender() == upstream =>
       // does some work in response to upstream
    case other =>
       // does some work in response to downstream
       // including sending messages to upstream and
       // `becoming` a stashing state waiting for Ack
       // to `unbecome`, then sending Ack downstream
       // (which will respect the backpressure).
  }
}
```

I have it on good authority from the akka-user mailing list that
there is no code in akka-streams that integrates actors with
streams, and in order to plug an Actor into a Stream and preserve
Ack-based backpressure, one would have to implement
[PushPullStage](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-customize.html).

It seems that we'd actually need two `PushPullStage`s here... one
for `upstream => SimpleActor` and one for `SimpleActor => upstream`.

My questions are:

1. Are there any libraries that offer integrations such as this between actors and streams?
2. Is there a simpler way of doing it than implementing bi-directional `PushPullStage` from scratch?
3. Is there any existing test framework that would allow such an implementation to be stress tested?

Comment: Have you tried using actor ask and `mapAsync`? If not, then writing a `PushPullStage` is still much easier than writing an `ActorProcessor`.

Comment: @jrudolph but I don't have a single response to a query (if that was the case, I'd have used REST instead of WebSockets). The publisher can send messages at any time.

Comment: I guess with "at any time" you mean whenever backpressure would allow it? How does that work exactly? If you produce a stream of outputs for each input element you could just model it that way and flatten the stream afterwards.

Comment: yeah, when backpressure allows. It is not a query/response protocol, the client and server can send messages to each other whenever they want (network allowing).

Comment: Ah, so input and output channels are completely separate and backpressure must be handled separately as well?

Comment: yes. I think this is quite normal for websockets applications.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the same as for any other bidirectional connection. That's a bit unfortunate about `Flow`: that you usually expect that input and output are necessarily connected when you can create them separately as well and just put them into a flow to get the right shape (maybe that's what you were alluding to in our ticket discussion as well).

Comment: yes, I wonder if perhaps the WebSockets API is not well suited to the typical use case. Was it you who wrote it? (in between saying how the reactive banana worked on the api for 1.5 years, Roland said something about you having written this bit)

Comment: We could provide an alternative entry point which would take a `Source[Message]` and a `Sink[Message]` separately. Would that be a better fit for applications like yours? (Behind the scenes we would still just call Flow.wrap and call the existing one.) With the flow confusion out of the picture we may now focus on how to implement backpressured Sources and Sinks.

Comment: Focussing on the output side first I haven't yet understood how exactly output elements are produced and how you want backpressure to work with that producer. What should happen when the websocket client isn't able to read more data?

Comment: E.g. see http://zuchos.com/blog/2015/05/23/how-to-write-a-subscriber-for-akka-streams/

Comment: It implements an `ActorPublisher` from scratch. Though, this is not recommended as it easy to introduce unbounded buffers this way. Generally, it is not possible to simply switch from a pull-based model (reactive-streams / akka-stream) to a push-style (actor message tell) inside of a processing pipeline. So, the question in your case is if you can slow down the ultimate producer of the outgoing data or not.

Comment: taking separate sink and source would be great! Backpressuring on the sink and source is pretty trivial, would it not just use the normal streams approach? As you know, TCP already has backpressure built in so as long as you're using the akka-io Acking/ResumeRead then all is good with the world. If I want application-tier backpressure (i.e. an explicit ack from the client) then that needs to be built in to the application protocol/api and is not akka specific.

Comment: maybe we should move this to a ticket or something somewhere? Or start a thread on the akka mailing list.

Comment: to answer your question, yes I can slow down the producer (above in the question). In the current impl it only sends Outgoing messages in response to an Ack, but I'm open to changing that to any kind of backpressure message.

Comment: I created https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/17609 to introduce another overload

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are using an `Ack`-based scheme on the application-side for slowing down the producer? Then, you need to implement an `ActorPublisher` as the answer below suggests. It seems the scheme may be general enough to warrant support directly in akka-stream in the future. I created https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/17610 to track that issue.

Answer (score 5):

I think the philosophy of akka-stream is to provide low-level bricks and build higher-level tools on top of them.
If you look at our recently released opensource library https://github.com/MfgLabs/akka-stream-extensions, you'll see that we have done that exactly. We provide some useful structures to make it easier to manage rate limiters, stateful processors, laziness & generators etc...
For actor integration, I think it should be possible to create some kind of helpers to make it easier to integrate actors with akka-stream trying to propagate backpressure. Akka-Stream is still young and the ecosystem keeps growing ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can integrate actors with streams.
There are special actors for this purpose: the actor publisher and actor subscriber.

It's all in here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-integrations.html

Of course you have to write the actor in such a way, that it works with the streams backpressure. But you do not need a push pull stage.

Comment: That does sound a hell of a lot easier than introducing a new phase and implementing its methods. I'd hoped to avoid having to write an intermediate actor, but it is looking like it is the only way forward --- implementing both publisher and subscriber. That's going to be a **lot** of boilerplate :-/